# Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise bug when dealing with large MOV files

Tags: windows-10, video, windows-explorer, quicktime, windows-10-v1607

We have identified a problem with Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise when dealing with large .MOV files (60-100GB in size).  I am a System Administrator and have now witnessed this issue on dozens of our corporate machines, and I can replicate it 100% of the time. The bug/issue is this:

When dealing with large video files (.MOV QT ProRes) that are 60-100 gigs in file size Explorer on Windows 10 will often freeze and come to a grinding halt. Sometimes simply highlighting a large file like this in Explorer is enough to cause it. To replicate the issue 100% of the time you can search for "MOV" from Explorer in a folder that contains 10-12 of these large files. As Explorer tries to locate/access these files it eats up all the physical memory, then all the virtual memory. A search like this will cause the freeze 100% of the time.

**This issue does not exist on Windows 7 boxes dealing with the same files.**

The obvious explanation would be that Windows 10 is trying to generate thumbnails for these large files. However I have disabled this feature (and besides, Windows 7 has the same feature). The next obvious thing I thought of was that the Windows Search service or Cortana was interfering. But I have disabled them, along with my A/V and everything else I can think of. The problem remains. I believe this has not been reported sooner because not many work with such large QT files on Windows 10.

Yesterday during testing I downloaded 4 different ISOs fresh (v1607), directly from Microsoft. I got Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Enterprise, Windows 10 Pro "N" version, Windows 10 Enterprise "N" version. Testing these four freshly installed in virtual machines has confirmed:

**The "N" versions of Windows 10 do not have this issue/bug.**

("N" versions exclude Windows Media Player and various **"related technologies"** such as DRM and codecs; summary: things that could cause this).

If anyone has any suggestions they would be welcomed (other then the obvious "you have a virus" or "defrag your hard drive" type of comments). I would like to find out exactly which service or feature is causing these freezes.

What is different in Explorer? Why doesn't Windows 7 have this problem? Why don't the "N" versions have this problem?

Comment: disable thumbnail creation in explorer options

Answer (score 2):

After many many hours and trying two dozen different fixes, I have solved this problem by removing two entries for MOV from the following registry locations:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\SystemPropertyHandlers
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers**

I have learned that the problem relates to Windows 10's Property Handlers: In Windows Vista and later, Windows has an extensible property system for storing and retrieving metadata in the files and data items that you access. Windows Explorer and the Windows Search system, along with other applications, use property handlers to read and modify this metadata.  They are usually called under the following circumstances:

•    During indexing of the file. This is done out-of-process, in an isolated process with restricted rights.

•    When files are accessed in Windows Explorer for the purpose of reading and writing property values. This is done in-process.

More info about Property Handlers:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144129(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd894084(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows 7, and Windows 10 "N" version do not have these same registry settings, which is why they did not have the same issue in my tests.

**Hopefully this helps someone else.**